# What is the difference between a local maximum and an unconstrained local maximum?

Tags: optimization

[image]

I can see that the definition of local maximum and unconstrained local maximum is written differently, but to me they look like they are defining the same thing. Furthermore, based on Fig 4.1, it looks like both $x^*$ and $y^*$ meet the definition of local maximum and unconstrained local maximum?

How do I distinguish between the 2 definitions?

Comment: Indeed there is something wrong with the second definition. The first is ok.

Comment: @Stefanos What do you think the second definition should have been?

Comment: Something like: **for every** $r>0$ such that ... and not **there is** $r>0$ such that... What do you think?

Comment: @Stefanos I thought the same thing too. But Daniel McLaury answer actually makes a lot of sense. Thanks for your input anyway.

Comment: Yes, indeed it makes sense. your welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume $\mathcal{D}$ refers to the domain of the function.

I'm not familiar with the term "unconstrained local maximum," but the definitions given here *are* different.  Look at the left-most point on the curve; say that it's located at $x = x_0$.  Then, taking a small ball $B(x_0, \varepsilon)$, $f(x_0) > f(y)$ for all $y \in B(x_0, \varepsilon) \cap \mathcal{D}$ so $x_0$ is a local maximum by this definition.

On the other hand, no ball $B(x_0, r)$ is contained in $\mathcal{D}$ -- $\mathcal{D}$ contains no points to the left of $x_0$ -- so $x_0$ cannot be an unconstrained local maximum by this definition.

So, in other words, according to these definitions an "unconstrained local maximum" is a "local maximum" which occurs in the middle of the domain, as opposed to at an endpoint.